# WSO2 scim can not get lastPasswordUpdateTime

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Cannot get **lastPasswordUpdateTime** of user from WSO2 using SCIM

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:SearchRequest"
  ],
  "attributes": [
      "emails", "groups", "name", "userName","lastPasswordUpdateTime","urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
  ],
  "filter": "userName eq 111111111111_222222222222",
  "domain": "PRIMARY",
  "startIndex": 1,
  "count": 10
}
```

Comment: What is the version of IS you are using? If you look at the user profile via the management console, can you see a value for lastPasswordUpdateTime?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna, version of IS 5.10.0. Yes,i have lassPasswordUpdateTime property from management console in user profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the `lastPasswordUpdateTime` value in the SCIM response, since there is no SCIM claim mapped to the local claim `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/lastPasswordUpdateTime`

You can map `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/lastPasswordUpdateTime` to a SCIM claim and use by following these steps.(Refere https://anuradha-15.medium.com/how-to-add-scim-extended-attributes-in-wso2-identity-server-71621f62c5d3 for more details)

1. Go to `scim2-schema-extension.config` file located in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/` folder and add the attribute definition.

```
{
"attributeURI":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:lastPasswordUpdateTime",
"attributeName":"lastPasswordUpdateTime",
"dataType":"string",
"multiValued":"false",
"description":"Last password update time",
"required":"false",
"caseExact":"false",
"mutability":"readOnly",
"returned":"default",
"uniqueness":"none",
"subAttributes":"null",
"canonicalValues":[],
"referenceTypes":[]
}
```

2. In the same file, add `lastPasswordUpdateTime` as a subattribute of `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User`
3. Restart the server.
4. Login to the management console and add an external claim.

```
Dialect URI: urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User
External Claim URI: urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:lastPasswordUpdateTime
(Attribute URI defined in the previous step)
Mapped Local Claim: http://wso2.org/claims/identity/lastPasswordUpdateTime
```

Then your request body would be

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:SearchRequest"
  ],
  "attributes": [
      "emails", "groups", "name", "userName","urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User.lastPasswordUpdateTime"
  ],
  "filter": "userName eq 111111111111_222222222222",
  "domain": "PRIMARY",
  "startIndex": 1,
  "count": 10
}
```